# Position of a custom layout on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm new to ABS and all things related to it. I'm also a new to Android development, so excuse noobish questions :)

I've spent all day learning how to use ABS. My activity consists of a MapView, and a search field (EditText) in the action bar along with a button (magnifying glass).

The EditText and Button are in a custom XML that I've added to the action bar menu. However, it seems to be RightAligned, that is, I can't seem to MOVE the custom layout to a location of my choice on the action bar (place it right next to the app title/icon).

My question? How to do move my custom layout to the left? OR, is there a better built-in alternative to this?

All I need is an EditText and a search button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use EditText to Search. Instead use a SearchView provided by ActionBarSherlock.
It's usage is the same is the SearchView from honeycomb API.
It's as simple as setting up a menu item.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget

There is also a [SearchView demo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/SearchViews.java)  in ABS samples

Comment: I came across that but found the implementation too complex. I'll give it another shot :(

Comment: The only complex thing I found if implementing Searchable config. You can avoid using Searchable configuration if you don't need to use suggestions. The SearchView widget is as easy to use as EditText.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot.
What about the button? Will it integrate with this thing?

Comment: The search button will be automatically displayed. When you click on it, the SearchVidget (text field with search icon) will appear - and on your keyboard (on most devices) you will see "search" IME button. When user clicks on it you will receive a callback method call. If user clicks back or up on actionbar - the search widget will be iconified back to a menu button.

Comment: Thanks! Just made it work. Much much simpler, efficient and visually pleasing :p

If you check see this comment, kindly tell me how to handle the search action (when the little button on the keyboard is pressed).